# Generalization of notion of convexity

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

I am searching for the correct term for the following, if it exists.

A set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is called $r$-convex if for any two points $x_1, x_2\in X$ such that there exists an arc of radius $r$ connecting these two points, at least one arc lies in the set $X$.

Note 1: Obviously, there are always two arcs of radius $r$ (if one exists) connecting two points.

Note 2: When $r\rightarrow +\infty$ we have the definition of convex set.

My main interest is efficient algorithms for computation of convex hulls based on this definition of convexity.

Comment: I think I would disagree with your first note as, surely, if we take the set X to be a semicircle of radius r then there is only one arc of radius r between any two points.

Comment: @Stijn, I think he's saying that there are two arcs in $\mathbb{R}^2$, not necessarily in $X$.

Comment: It seems like a weird notion. Where does it come up?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about two arcs in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Dylan At the moment I am working on algorithm for rounding sharp corners in polygon. Let $P$ be a set of points lying in polygon. I need to find $P^\prime$ such that its border consists of segments and arcs. Arc radius should not exceed $r$ and there are no sharp angles (less than $\pi$). I have guess that $P\prime = \mathbb{R}^2 \ co_r (\mathbb{R}^2 \ P)$, where $co_r$ is convex hull in the sense of definition above. My idea is to apply algorithms for regular convex hull with modified definition of convexity.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand something. First consider a square whose sides are $2r$ for $r > 0$. Now put a disk of radius $r$ at each vertex of the square. It seems like the part of the square that is in none of the disks is convex by this definition. This shape has four pointy spots.

Comment: Is $r$ fixed or it can vary? If it is fixed, I think your definition is the same as saying that a set is convex if you can touch it from outside by a sphere of radius $r$ at any of its boundary points. This notion exists for a general shape $s$ or general function $f$, and called $s$-convex or $f$-convex. I guess if $r$ can vary then you can just consider a family of shapes.

Comment: @FedorNikitin one thing I don't quite understand is how your task of rounding the corners of a polygon relates to an upper bound on the radius. The radius of corners is 0, and the one for straight-line segments is infinity; could it be that you actually mean to limit curvature, which is infinite for corners?

Comment: Agree with Jay's comment -- intuitively, the definition seems to need a modification. How about something like this? "$X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is $r$-convex if, for each $x \in X$, there exists a disk $D$ of radius $r$ such that $x \in D$ and $D \subseteq X$."

Comment: Consider any finite $\ X\subset \mathbb R^2.\ $ Then according to your definition, $\ X\ $ is $r$-convex, right? Also $\ \mathbb Q^2\ $ is $r$-convex, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not comment posts because of too small reputation :-) It will change I hope.

In connection with usul's comment:

Also strongly convex sets are considered. Roughly speaking, one could require that together with two points the whole lens is contained in a set. For a definition see for instance here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4347.pdf